# Monitor tcp on android (download locations)

Tags: android, url, tcp, download

Is it possible to see where an app is downloading from in Android. For example if you start an app for the first time it will often download additional files from a server.  Can I find out the url of this server/download?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  [Debug Proxy](https://apkpure.com/debug-proxy/com.dans.apps.webd)

need root access

Comment: I can't get it to work. Do I have to add a proxy ip in wifi settings. The apps just don't load